# Disable proxy for NSURLSession

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I am finding that when my iOS device automatically configures a proxy, all of my NSURLSessions are using it for downloads/uploads/requests. This becomes a problem when I'm trying to make those requests from other devices on the same local network. I need to disable the proxy that the device autodetects for NSURLSession.

Every post everywhere indicates how to set the proxy dictionary, however, I can't find anywhere how to make sure the NRURLSession doesn't use a proxy.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you provide an *empty* proxy dictionary when creating the session configuration, NSURLSession should ignore the system-provided proxies in all sessions created with that session configuration.

If you're trying to override it for something where you didn't create the session (e.g. third-party frameworks, web views, etc.), you can *usually* solve that by creating and registering (globally) an NSURLProtocol that takes the requests and reissues them in your own session (adding some custom header so that you don't keep reissuing the same request in an infinite loop).  There are some basic examples of writing custom protocols on Apple's website.

Comment: To that, I should add the caveat that out-of-process web views (WKWebView) can't be overridden in that way, AFAIK.